# Solovay-Kitaev algorithm with non-constant number of qubits

Tags: universal-gates, solovay-kitaev-algorithm

The Solovay-Kitaev algorithm gives a construction to $\epsilon$-approximate any $m$-qubit unitary $U$ with $O(m \log(m/\epsilon))$ elementary gates, provided $m$ is a constant.

My question is: if the dimension of $U$ is polynomial in the input size, is it possible to approximate it in polynomial time?

Comment: Do you mean $m$ is polynomial in the input size? Because the dimension of $U$ is exponential in $m$.

Comment: @ChrisD no, I mean that the dimension is polynomial, meaning that $m$ is logarithmic in the input size. If $m$ is polynomial then it should not be possible to approximate any unitary efficiently.

Comment: The algorithm assumes you have a lookup table of initial approximations to some fixed precision, which in turn requires you to enumerate all possible gate sequences up to some fixed length which scales as $\mathrm{dim}(U)^2$. This enumeration is exponential in this length, so rapidly becomes impractical as $\mathrm{dim}(U)$ increases.